# JQuery help show more/less with formatting within div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm running into an issue finding and creating a solution with show more/less functionality using JQuery with formatting within the targeted div. In the snippet below, null items populate with text as my page's form is filled out. At 150 text characters visible (ignore formatting and tags), the show more/less functionality needs kick in and hide characters greater than 150 with a link to show more or less.

I've tried using this http://code-tricks.com/jquery-read-more-less-example/ as a base, but am having trouble getting that code to work with a div with tags within it.

```
<div class="search-keywords more">
    <p style="display: none;" id="searchCriteria">All records</p>
    <p style="display: inline;" id="emEnvSubclass">EM Environmental Subclass = </p>
    <p style="display: inline; font-style: italic;" id="emEnvSubclassValue">Atomsphere OR Created Greenspace OR Forests</p>
    <p style="display: inline;" id="emSourceColl"> AND EM Source/Collection = </p>
    <p style="display: inline; font-style: italic;" id="emSourceCollValue">Other OR US EPA</p>
    <p style="display: none;" id="cicesSec">null</p>
    <p style="display: none; font-style: italic;" id="cicesSecValue">null</p>
    <p style="display: none;" id="fegsEnvSubclass">null</p>
    <p style="display: none; font-style: italic;" id="fegsEnvSubclassValue">null</p>
</div>
```

Thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: Since I cant add comments yet, maybe your code is not updating when the dynamic text is being added? If that is the case than try adding a change event to your < p> tags to test when they are over 150 characters.

Comment: Thanks Egregory, I made a jsfiddle to show the issue I'm running into. See the bottom show more example: http://jsfiddle.net/yttf88zp/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**UPDATED ANSWER:**

If it doesn't have to be fixed at 150 characters and it can be based on a div size, you can use this plugin: [dotdotdot.frebsite.nl](http://dotdotdot.frebsite.nl)

**ORIGINAL ANSWER:**
Here's a working fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/manishie/mgz8tec0/

You need to replace:

```
var content = $(this).html();
```

with:

```
var content = $(this).text();
```

That will strip out the html tags when you're getting the count of characters.

Comment: Turns out my issue is still present - I should've been more specific. I have formatting within the div that's lost with this solution. 

The span class is lost in the working fiddle

Comment: does it have to be fixed 150 characters or can it be based on a div size?  if so, you can use this plugin: http://dotdotdot.frebsite.nl/

Comment: Thank you manishie, I think that's the closest to the solution yet. I'm running into issues with the data updates but that is a totally different issue. If you post yours as an answer, I'll accept it. Thanks again!